# Write a new file with defined function on Ruby

Tags: ruby, function

In *Learn Ruby The Hard Way* book on exercise 19, it says one should take the provided function:

```
def cheese_and_crackers(cheese_count, boxes_of_crackers)
  puts "You have #{cheese_count} cheeses!"
  puts "You have #{boxes_of_crackers} boxes of crackers!"
  puts "Man that's enough for a party!"
  puts "Get a blanket.\n"
end
```

and explore different approaches with it. I tried to explore the function's arguments and write a text with it:

```
file = ARGV.first

puts "Let's make a test?"
puts "Does the output file exist? #{File.exist?(arquivo)} "
puts "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."

$stdin.gets

def success(price, recipe)
  puts """Text goes on like this:
  In order to become a coder, You must dedicate yourself.\n
  For that, you must pay a price, such as #{price}\n
  Becoming a coder also requires #{recipe}\n"""
end

puts "What is the price to pay in order to become a coder?"
price = $stdin.gets
puts "What are the fundamental components in order to become a coder?"
recipe = $stdin.gets

coder = success(price, recipe)

motivational = File.open(file, 'w')
motivational.write(coder)

puts "Read this every day."
```

But I can't seem to make it write the function into a new `test.txt` file. The `test.txt` file comes out empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `puts`, you're writing to stdout, but the return value will be empty.

Change this:

```
def success(price, recipe)
  return """Text goes on like this:
  In order to become a coder, You must dedicate yourself.\n
  For that, you must pay a price, such as #{price}\n
  Becoming a coder also requires #{recipe}\n"""
end
```

Then also:

```
motivational.close()
```

EDIT: Here's an extended explanation: when calling `puts`, you're just writing the string to stdout, which is the default output for programs. Methods (functions) can have a return value. For your `success` method, you need to return the string, so that you can write it in your file. If you call `puts` instead of `return`, the `success` method will not return any value, therefore leaving the file empty.

As for the `close()` call, it is advisable to close the file stream before your script ends.

Take a look at these references for more information:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/2/

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html

Comment: Can you be clearer? What do you mean by return value? Also, what means return inside the function?

Comment: @PetrusLee sure! Just added a more detailed explanation.